# Does C# generics support type signature constraints?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

One of the benefits with C++ templates is that you (implicitly) can require a certain type signature (e.g. type T needs to have a function x that takes no parameters and returns an int). Does C# generics support something similar?

I am aware of constraints based on base class or interface but this is not what I am looking for.

(As a C++ programmer learning C# I might be mistaken that this is a feature that you would want in C#. Any comments on this would be appriciated as well...)

Comment: But interface constraints are already a pretty good way to express something like `T implements a method X() matching some signature`, don't you think?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nothing except for the constraints you have already seen (which do, to be fair, cover a lot of common scenarios). There are some common workarounds:

- `dynamic`, in 4.0
- manual duck-typing using either reflection or IL generation etc

none of these have static type-checking etc, though.

Comment: Dynamic is probably the closest I can get. In fact, I often think of C++ templates as a "dynamic compile time language" (which probably is a phrase that doesn't make sense to anybody but me :)

Comment: @Tobias I'd have gone with "static-checked duck-typed" ;p (`dynamic` has implications of runtime, but I know what you mean)

Comment: and suddenly it makes sense to everybody :)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, through an interface.  You can define a generic object that has a type that must have a specific interface implemented.  Within that interface, you would essentially be forcing any object added to that generic, list for instance, to have a specific signature.

Whether or not that's what you're *not* looking for, that's how you accomplish it. :)

Comment: That still doesn't cover all options, though - constructors with parameters, operators, static methods, etc...

Comment: @Marc Well there isn't a perfect solution in this situation -- just as you noted in your answer.  The OP is going to have to bend a little to accomplish his task. And he may not need any of the things you mentioned.  He wants his generic class to conform to "function x that takes no parameters and returns an int"

Comment: @Marc, I agree, and supporting constraints on non-default constructors would be nice IMHO. The others, not so much, *especially* operators :)

Comment: @Marc But by all means, this is just a canned solution.  He is more than welcome to attack this from any angle that fits his needs :)

Comment: This requires the type of the type parameter to adhere to the needs of the generic class which is sometimes not what you want. (I am not trying to solve some particular problem but trying to understand what possibilities C# generics provides).

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. It's mainly caused by the differences between C++ templates and C# generics:

When you compile C++ template, the resulting code has types like `vector<int>` and `vector<string>`. This means the compiler has to know all the possible type parameters, but it also means it can check them for correctness.

When you compile C# generic type, you are actually creating just one generic type: `List<T>`. Because of this, the C# compiler doesn't have to know all the possible types at compile type, which means you can have generic types in binary libraries, which is not possible with C++. But this also means that you can't check all the types. To be able to do something like that, there are constraints, but they can't do several things C++'s compile time checking can, like checking the presence of certain methods (without using interface or some base class) or the presence of suitable operators.

In C# 4, you can achieve effect somewhat similar to this kind of templates using `dynamic`, but this does *no* compile-time checking, which means you lose safety – you can put in a type that doesn't have the appropriate members and you won't find out until you reach that line of code at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

No. This is what `interface`s are for. Create an `interface` that defined the contract you want to enforce in the type constraints. Then specify that in the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

There are 5 types of constraints you can put onto generics in .Net:

1. Derivation constraints state the ascendancy of a type parameter.
2. Interface constraints are interfaces that are implemented by the type parameter.
3. Value type constraints restrict a type parameter to a value type.
4. Reference type constraints restrict a type parameter to a reference type.
5. Constructor constraints stipulate that the type parameter has a default or parameterless constructor.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) page shows more information.

Comment: "I am aware of constraints based on base class or interface but this is not what I am looking for."

Answer (score 0):

Nope, not supported in c#.  Like you said, the closest thing requires you to have the classes implement a common interface.

You *could* try to mimic the behavior with reflection, by looking for the method by the signature, but that's a runtime constraint, and not a compile-time constraint.

Answer (score 0):

No, C# does not have constraints like that.

As you know, generic constraints can only enforce inheritance of a base class or an interface, or a few other constraints (constructor constraint `new()`, reference type constraint `class`, value type constraint `struct`).

You might be able to achieve your desired behavior using **delegates**, and there are many Generic delegates available.
For example, `Func<int>` is a delegate that takes no parameters and returns an `int`.  `Func<string, DateTime, int>` takes a `string` and `DateTime` and returns an `int`, etc...